# Mongoose Async Call Issue with Find Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have var `movieRecommendation` which is being populated from data coming from Mongo DB. Issue is Mongoose `Movie.findOne()` call is asycn call which is not allowing me to get my final populated `movieRecommendation` which I need to send back as response.

```
exports.getRecommendation=function(req,res){
var movieRecommendation = [];
var id=req.params.id;
console.log('----- Get User Recommendation - ' +  id);
var url = 'http://52.8.48.113:8080/recommender-server/recommender/v1/recommendations/'+id+'.do';
//make http get request
request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, recommendations) {
       // res.json(recommendations);

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        recommendations.forEach(function(entry) {

             **Movie.findOne({'id':parseInt(entry.itemId)},function(err, movieData){**
                entry.movie = movieData;
                movieRecommendation.push(entry);
               //console.log('rec', movieRecommendation);
                 console.log(movieRecommendation.length);
            });


        });

    }
    console.log("====Final========"+movieRecommendation.length);
    //Output = 0

});

    res.json(movieRecommendation); // Here movieRecommendation is coming as black Array

};
```

Please let me know how I can get finally populated `movieRecommendation` var at end to make it available for response.

Comment: Never use regular `for` loops to execute async calls, because they won't wait your async calls to return. Try [`async.each`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each) or a module that implement promises, like `q`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) or `bluebird`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each).

Answer (score 0):

For this type of issues we can use [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. To populate the data finally once all the operations done, we can use **async.each** collection from **Async Library**.

**For example:**
NOTE:Install Async by this command
    **npm install async** to use async library

```
    var async = require("async");

    var recomenmendations = [{"data2" : "value2"} , {"data1" : "value2"}, {"data3" : "value3"}, {"data4" : "value4"} ]  

    var movieRecommendation = [];

    async.each(recomenmendations,

      function(recomenmendationItem, callback){


            console.log("Here you can query the required data using current recomenmendations ITEM");
            console.log(recomenmendationItem);
            callback();

             // Movie.find({'id':parseInt(recomenmendationItem.itemId)},function(err, movieData){

          //           recomenmendationItem.movie = movieData;
          //           movieRecommendation.push(entry);
          //        callback();        
          //    });



      },

      function(err){

        console.log("here you can send your resopnse");
        console.log("This section will be executed once all the recomenmendations are processed");
        //res.json(movieRecommendation)

      }
    );
```

You can query the mongoDB as shown with comment section. You should use **callback()** once all the operations performed for an iteration.

Comment: Hi Prabhu , Given code is working fine as expected but when I am making Mongo call before callback() again I am facing same issue with previous .

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in one of my comments, use the `callback` passed to the iterator function and call it inside the `Movie.findOne()` callback. That way, `async.each` will know when each step has finished:

```
async.each(recomendations, function (recomendationItem, callback) {

    Movie.findOne({'id':parseInt(entry.itemId)},function(err, movieData){

        if (err) return callback(err); // if you have an error on you search, just pass it to the iterator callback

        recommendationItem.movie = movieData;
        movieRecommendation.push(recommendationItem);

        callback();
    });

}, function (error) {

    if (error) return res.json ({ error: error }); // you should also check if an error ocurred

    res.json(movieRecomendation);

});
```

Just to point out: you can also use `async.eachSeries`, that will just call the next step of your iteration when the previous one has returned (if that matters to you, but I think it's not your case though) and it has the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

@Vivek Panday **replace the following code inside your *exports.getRecommendation function* to get your expected output**. We don't need to use the **count** variable if we use the **callback** function. And an important thing is we have to use **callback();** once all the process done. I think you have not used callback function properly in The example you have worked out. Use the following code If there is any issue please let me know.

```
     var async = require('async');
     var request = require("request");

      var movieRecommendation = [];
      var id=req.params.id;
      console.log('----- Get User Recommendation - ' +  id);
      var url = 'http://52.8.48.113:8080/recommender-server/recommender/v1/recommendations/'+id+'.do';

      //make http get request
      request({
          url: url,
          json: true
      }, function (error, response, recommendations) {

          if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

              console.log('recommendation lenght '+ recommendations.length);

              async.each(recommendations,

                function(recommendationItem, callback){            

                  Movie.findOne({'id':parseInt(recommendationItem.itemId)},function(err, movieData){

                      recommendationItem.movie = movieData;
                      movieRecommendation.push(recommendationItem);
                      //you have to use callback(); once all your process is done
                      callback();

                  });

                },

                function(err){
                  //you should use this function, this will be execute once all the process done
                  console.log(movieRecommendation);
                  console.log("finally callback");
                  res.json(movieRecommendation);

                }

                );

          }


    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried as per given suggestion above ..
    var async = require("async");

```
var recomenmendations = [{"data2" : "value2"} , {"data1" : "value2"}, {"data3" : "value3"}, {"data4" : "value4"} ]  

var movieRecommendation = [];

async.each(recomenmendations,

  function(recomenmendationItem, callback){


        console.log("Here you can query the required data using current recomenmendations ITEM");
        console.log(recomenmendationItem);


         // Movie.find({'id':parseInt(recomenmendationItem.itemId)},function(err, movieData){

               recomenmendationItem.movie = movieData;
                movieRecommendation.push(entry);
                 console.log("any data"); // line y     
          });

callback();

  },

  function(err){

    console.log("here you can send your resopnse"); // line x
    console.log("This section will be executed once all the       
    recomenmendations are processed");
    //res.json(movieRecommendation)

  }
);
```

But still face same issue line x is printing before line y ,which is making again same issue.

However I have tried something given below and achieved expected result .

```
exports.getRecommendation=function(req,res){
var movieRecommendation = [];
var id=req.params.id;
console.log('----- Get User Recommendation - ' +  id);
var url = 'http://52.8.48.113:8080/recommender-server/recommender/v1/recommendations/'+id+'.do';
//make http get request
request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, recommendations) {
       // res.json(recommendations);

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

    console.log('recommendation lenght '+ recommendations.length);

       // recommendations.forEach(function(entry) {
        var count=0;
        async.each(recommendations,function(recommendationItem){
           //  console.log(recommendationItem);
            Movie.findOne({'id':parseInt(recommendationItem.itemId)},function(err, movieData){
                recommendationItem.movie = movieData;
                movieRecommendation.push(recommendationItem);
                count ++;
                console.log('final res length : ' +  movieRecommendation.length);
              console.log('final res length count : ' +  count +'  and item recomm lenght ' +  recommendations.length );

            if(count === recommendations.length){
                console.log(' =====Final=====> here you can send your response =========' +   movieRecommendation.length);

                res.json(movieRecommendation);
            }

            });

           // callback();

        });


    }


});
```

};

Still I am open for any feedback and suggestions.

Comment: You should use the `callback` passed to the iterator function and call it inside the `Movie.findOne()` callback. That way, `async.each` will know when each step has finished. So, you don't need all that logic that you used.

Comment: I just wrote an answer. See if it works for you, please.